# Weird behavior while selecting date in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to select a date using selenium+java but its behaving very weirdly.
Apart from that i am getting element not found exception.
I am passing the date in the function
What i am doing wrong
Below is the code

```
public class date_automation {
WebDriver driver = null;

@BeforeTest
public void initialise() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/");
}

@Test
public void test_calendar() throws InterruptedException {
    WebElement departure_date = driver.findElement(By.id("departureCalendar"));
    departure_date.click();
    selectDateInCalendar("23/01/2022");
}

public void selectDateInCalendar(String date) throws InterruptedException {

    Date CurrentDate = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
        Date expectedDate = newDateFormat.parse(date);
        String day = new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(expectedDate);
        String month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(expectedDate);
        String year = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(expectedDate);
        System.out.println(day + "*****" + month + "*****" + year);
        String expectedMonthYear = month + " " + year;
        System.out.println(expectedMonthYear);
        String displayDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='DayPicker-Caption']")).getText();
        while (true) {

            if (expectedMonthYear.equals(displayDate)) {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='" + day + "']")).click();
            } else {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='DayPicker-NavButton DayPicker-NavButton--next']"))
                        .click();
            }

        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@AfterTest
public void cleanup() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

Comment: What exception are you getting and for what code line? What do you mean by `behaving very weirdly`?

Comment: Its going till month Dec 2023 and its throwing exception
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@class='DayPicker-

Comment: @ManishB In your code, you need to place this line `String displayDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='DayPicker-Caption']")).getText();` inside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you need to place this line `String displayDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='DayPicker-Caption']")).getText();` inside the while loop.

I tried my hand too and was able to select the dates by:

- Clicking on the desired datepicker object
- Check the displayed Month and Year and see if it matches with the desired/expected Month and Year we want to select
- Keep on clicking on the next-month button(as long as it is not disabled) if the match fails in step 2
- Once the desired Month and Year are reached, select the desired date

Please refer the following code to select the departure and arival dates:

```
package usecase;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class DatePicker {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    /**
     * selects the date provided in d/m/yyyy format
     */
    public static void selectDate(By dateObject, String date) {
        driver.findElement(dateObject).click();
        SimpleDateFormat sdfInput = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat sdfOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMMM yyyy");
        try {
            String outputDate = sdfOutput.format(sdfInput.parse(date));
            System.out.println(outputDate);
            String outputDay = outputDate.split("-")[0];
            String outputMY = outputDate.split("-")[1];
            String displayedHeading;
            while (!(displayedHeading = driver.findElement(By.className("DayPicker-Caption")).getText())
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(outputMY)) {
                WebElement gotoNextMonth = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[aria-label='Next Month']"));
                if (!gotoNextMonth.getAttribute("class").contains("interactionDisabled")) // click next month button
                                                                                            // only if it is NOT
                                                                                            // disabled
                    gotoNextMonth.click();
                else {
                    System.err.println("The Date " + date + " could not be selected");
                    break;
                }
            }
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='DayPicker-Day']/div[text()='" + outputDay + "']")).click();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/");
        selectDate(By.id("departureCalendar"), "25/6/2022");
        selectDate(By.id("returnCalendar"), "1/7/2022");
        Thread.sleep(3000); // Let me see what happened on screen
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**Demo:**
[image]